# Java application start point

Tags: java

I downloaded a simple java app and I want to know which file I need to run to start. There are several classes in the project and I do not know which one is the main one. Thank you.

Comment: is the app a .jar or do you have .java files?

Comment: I have the .java files.

Comment: Are you using an ide?

Comment: Yes, intellij idea.

Comment: well the op says they have the .java files so it shouldn't bee too hard then, so you might post the file structure so might be some help also what kind of app it is too, or where you got the simple app

Comment: This is the app: https://github.com/nhooyr/java-tanktank

Comment: Search for the class with the `main` method. It's inside the class `Main.java` of your project.

Comment: You should edit your question and include all those additional information, especially the link to the project. In the current state your question is too broad as it doesn't contain all information needed to form an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Search for the class with the `main` method, that is the method where program execution starts. It looks like

```
public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
```

It's inside the class `Main.java` of your project:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Open the project in an **IDE** and run this class. Or do it manually in the console like:

```
javac Main.java
java Main
```

Only `.jar` files can automatically be started like `.exe` files. Your project only contains code and you will need to *compile and run* it on your own.

Comment: This is valid for all java projects ? A project has only one class with a main method ?

Comment: No, it could have multiple. You will then need to find the one that is meant to start the application. For example there could be other `main` methods used for debugging purpose which start some sub-applications. A C-program often has multiple `.exe` files too if you take a look at some of your installed apps on your computer. The programmer should clearly indicate which one is the **main** application. For example by including a *readme* file.

Answer (score 0):

You should have public static void method called "main" taking array of String as parameter in one of the classes. Something like below

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println("test");
}
```

This is your entry point.

@Edit
OP added code so here is an answer update:
Your entry point is in class Main and method is

```
public static void main(final String[] args
```

If you're using intellij just run click on this method and select Run "Main.main()"